# ОШИБКА blocked by CORS при создании класса PHP

Tags: javascript, php, файлы, fetch

Есть такой код

```js
document.querySelector('#sellForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let bodySell = new FormData(this);
  bodySell.append('action', 'sell');

  fetch('http://colorshop/core/core.php', {
    method: 'post',
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    body: bodySell
  }).then(response => {
    return response.text();
  }).then(res => {
    this.reset(); // очищаем поля формы 
    console.log(res);
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="sellForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="createImg" class="inputfile" accept="image/*" />
  <label for="createImg">Выберети файл</label><br>
  <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Название" id="createName"><br>
  <textarea name="descr" id="createDescr" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Описание"></textarea><br>
  <input name="cost" type="number" placeholder="Цена" id="createCost">

  <input type="submit" id="goCreate" />
</form>
```

При отправке(даже еще не отправляя, просто открыв вкладку с этим скриптом) вылазит такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в php выполняется такой код:

```js
<?php
    cors();
    session_start();//session
    error_reporting(E_ALL);//show all errors

    // auto load classes
    spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
        include './classes/' . $class_name . '.php';
    });

    $do = new Do();

    switch ($action) {
        case 'sell':
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $descr = $_POST['descr'];
            $cost = $_POST['cost'];
            
            $do->doSell($_FILES, $name, $descr, $cost);
            break;
    } 

    function cors() {  
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
            header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
        }

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
        }
    }
?>
```

В нем создается экземпляр класса Do

```js
require_once('connect.php');

class Do extends Connect {
  // получить соединение с бд
  protected $conn;

  public
  function doSell($file, $name, $descr, $cost) {
    $conn = parent::conn();

    $file_name = $file['file']['name'];
    $file_size = $file['file']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $file['file']['tmp_name'];
    $seller = $_SESSION['userName'].
    ':'.$_SESSION['userId'];

    if ($file_size < 2097152) {
      echo time();
      move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'goods/'.$file_name);

      $sel = $conn - > query("INSERT INTO `goods` (`name`, `descr`, `cost`, `img`, `seller`) VALUES ('$name', '$descr', '$cost', 'img', '$seller')");
    } else echo 'img';
  }
}
```

В целом не важно, что в нем находится, ведь даже если я напишу в нем echo 123, то он всё равно выдается ошибку.
Если не создавать экземпляр, то всё окей

Для справки напишу, что в том же месте, что и Do, создаются и другие экземпляры классов, которые работает правильно.

Добавлю еще видео, которое демонстрирует, что без класса Do всё работает(так же есть и другие классы)
вот ссылка

https://vk.com/im?peers=435058534_-123083697&sel=458561605&z=video261429253_456239116%2F6603a54a5fe58cd7dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хохо, ответ был скрыт в названии класса.
Я поменял название на ToDo, и был удивлен, что всё заработало.
Я так и не понял как связана ошибка с названием класса

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблема в порядка вызова, session_start

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php

Замечание:

Для использования сессий на основе cookie, функция session_start() должна быть вызвана перед выводом чего бы то ни было в браузер.

переставьте

cors();
session_start();//session

на

session_start();//session
cors();

Comment: спасибо, но к сожалению это не помогло(

Answer (score 0):

Так же нужно разрешить заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

```
    function cors() {   
      if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
     }
```

возможно проблема в этом куске кода, уберите проверку. Убедитесь что Access-Control-Allow-Origin, добавляется в header

Comment: К сожалению и так тоже не работает(

Comment: доменное имя в запросе http://colorshop/core/core.php, без .com, .ru так и должно быть?

Comment: да это локальный сервер

Comment: И здесь проблема скорее всего не в этом, ведь у меня точно таким же образом выполняются другие операции

Comment: могу посоветовать еще онлайн сервис для тестирования cors запросов
https://www.test-cors.org/
если не знаете. Возможно будет полезен

Comment: кстати на локальной машине какой у вас веб сервер? если apache то в файле apache.conf нужно разрешить cors

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

* -  означает разрешить все, здесь можно вписать домен с которого принимать запросы

Comment: для nginx
https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Answer (score 0):

А что у вас в $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']? Попробуйте использовать:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

вместо:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
```

Возможно, браузер не отправляет Origin. Или сервер настроен так, что не заполняет переменную $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'].

Comment: тоже не работает